# jquery load() function working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, load

jquery noob trying to dynamically update a div (#allimages) with new html dynamically created by a PHP script (hpimages.php). Seems like load() would be the thing, and I found a nice function on doing the updating [here](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/02/26/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/). Here's the code I'm using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$("#allimages").load("hpimages.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$("#allimages").load('hpimages.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 1000);
```

It works great in Firefox ... keeps reloading behind the scenes so that when there is new content, it appears on the page. However, it behaves differently in Chrome: #allimages gets updated every second, but instead of REPLACING the existing html with the html coming from hpimages.php, it appends the new html to the old, so the page starts to grow huge with repeated content. Any ideas on how to fix in Chrome?

Comment: I should add that I am running this on the server, not locally, as I can see that that issue has been addressed in other questions.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty work around would be to empty the div first.

```
$("#allimages").html("").load( //...
```

I would also break down your page to something testable and report a bug. You may find that you messed it up when you are reducing the code down.

Comment: thanks for the quick response ... I did try emptying the div, but that makes the page blink every time it refreshes.

Comment: That's kind of what will have to happen. Since it only causes an issue in chrome (are you sure not safari/webkit also?), you could check for webkit/chrome and set `html("")` in a separate if statement. Then have the `load` happen for everyone.

Comment: Wasn't me ... though I'm still looking for a blinkless solution. can't seem to find other bugs in the code, and it still works perfectly in FF.